# ckeditor not saving in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, crud

I wanted to learn how to make a cms. I know crud operations but when I want to take some value from ckeditor and put it in MySQL database is not working. Is making me nervous I know I did a mistake but I don't know where.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_POST['editor']) && !empty($_POST['editor'])){
    $content = $_POST['editor'];
  }else{
    $empty_error = "didnt send to database";
  }
  if (isset($content) && !empty($content)) {
     $insert_q = "INSERT INTO `contact`(continut) VALUES ('$content')";
      if (mysqli_query($conn,$insert_q)) {
     // code...
     }else{
       $submit_error ="submit didnt work";
     }
  }

}
?>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
             <div class="card-body">
               <div class="card-title">Add</div>
               <hr>
                <form action=" " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <textarea name="editor" class="ckeditor" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </form>
             </div>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the results of your (2 hours) debugging process? Is $content set? Is there an mysqli error? ...?

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` will not be set. There is no element that has this name.

Comment: I have a table with continut and id where continut is TEXT and when i submit is glitching(refresh i think)  my page and when i check table is empty.

Comment: also `form action=" "` (with the space for action) is weird. Leave it empty/remove it  or insert a valid value.

Comment: you set a `$empty_error` but you never check for it or display it. This could have told you what went wrong if you had the same test for `$_POST['submit']`

Comment: Thanks ia am a f,....noob. HAVE A NICE DAY SIR!